# OpenVPN and wlan0 won't play nice

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I've setup a WIFI connection using /etc/network/interfaces that works very well.

```
udooer@udooneo:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# Loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Primary network interface
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet static
address 192.168.7.2
netmask 255.255.255.252

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 
### Add a line like this for every Wifi network defined in the wpa_supplicant.conf file
iface home inet dhcp
iface work inet dhcp
iface iphone inet dhcp
```

The problem is that when I am booting my device (and my OpenVPN client is also starting, I'm seeing that my wlan0 connection is constantly DISCONNECTING and CONNECTING.). It's as if my OpenVPN and wlan0 connection are fighting. If I don't start the OpenVPN client the WIFI connects just fine and doesn't disconnect.

This is what I'm seeing in syslog (constantly, goes on and on like this until I shut down the openvpn service) :

```
Dec 18 22:33:31 localhost ntpdate[1320]: step time server 85.88.55.5 offset 30407602.944281 sec
Dec 18 22:33:32 localhost ntpd[1893]: ntpd 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Wed Nov 11 18:05:09 UTC 2015 (1)
Dec 18 22:33:32 localhost ntpd[1894]: proto: precision = 0.666 usec
Dec 18 22:33:32 localhost ntpd[1894]: ntp_io: estimated max descriptors: 1024, initial socket boundary: 16
Dec 18 22:33:32 localhost ntpd[1894]: Listen and drop on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0 UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:32 localhost ntpd[1894]: Listen and drop on 1 v6wildcard :: UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:32 localhost ntpd[1894]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1 UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:32 localhost ntpd[1894]: Listen normally on 3 usb0 192.168.7.2 UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:32 localhost ntpd[1894]: Listen normally on 4 lo ::1 UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:32 localhost ntpd[1894]: Listen normally on 5 usb0 fe80::4c71:9eff:fe8c:405b UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:32 localhost ntpd[1894]: Listen normally on 6 wlan0 fe80::7eec:79ff:fecb:3f01 UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:32 localhost ntpd[1894]: peers refreshed
Dec 18 22:33:32 localhost ntpd[1894]: Listening on routing socket on fd #23 for interface updates
Dec 18 22:33:32 localhost ntpd[1894]: Deferring DNS for 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org 1
Jan  1 00:00:08 localhost ovpn-client[1375]: message repeated 3 times: [ write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)]
Dec 18 22:33:33 localhost ovpn-client[1375]: [UNDEF] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Dec 18 22:33:33 localhost ovpn-client[1375]: SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Dec 18 22:33:33 localhost ovpn-client[1375]: Restart pause, 2 second(s)
Dec 18 22:33:34 localhost ntpd[1894]: Deferring DNS for 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org 1
Dec 18 22:33:34 localhost ntpd[1894]: Deferring DNS for 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org 1
Dec 18 22:33:34 localhost ntpd[1894]: Deferring DNS for 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org 1
Dec 18 22:33:34 localhost ntpd[1894]: Deferring DNS for ntp.ubuntu.com 1
Dec 18 22:33:34 localhost ntpd[1897]: signal_no_reset: signal 17 had flags 4000000
Dec 18 22:33:34 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.117.
Dec 18 22:33:34 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Dec 18 22:33:34 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.117 on wlan0.IPv4.
Dec 18 22:33:35 localhost dhclient: bound to 192.168.1.117 -- renewal in -30374924 seconds.
Dec 18 22:33:35 localhost ovpn-client[1375]: WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Dec 18 22:33:35 localhost ovpn-client[1375]: Socket Buffers: R=[163840->131072] S=[163840->131072]
Dec 18 22:33:35 localhost ovpn-client[1375]: UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Dec 18 22:33:35 localhost ovpn-client[1375]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]52.91.25.92:1194
Dec 18 22:33:35 localhost ovpn-client[1375]: TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]52.91.25.92:1194, sid=42da4f6c 9301d3d6
Dec 18 22:33:35 localhost ntpd[1894]: ntpd exiting on signal 15
Dec 18 22:33:35 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.117 on wlan0.
Dec 18 22:33:35 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.117.
Dec 18 22:33:35 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Dec 18 22:33:36 localhost dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x6bf80137)
Dec 18 22:33:36 localhost ntpd_intres[1897]: parent died before we finished, exiting
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost wpa_action: creating sendsigs omission pidfile: /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost wpa_action: bssid=00:25:9c:4d:18:36
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost wpa_action: ssid=MYWIFI
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost wpa_action: id=0
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost wpa_action: id_str=home
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost wpa_action: mode=station
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost wpa_action: pairwise_cipher=CCMP
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost wpa_action: group_cipher=CCMP
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost wpa_action: key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost wpa_action: wpa_state=COMPLETED
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost wpa_action: p2p_device_address=7c:ec:79:cb:3f:01
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost wpa_action: address=7c:ec:79:cb:3f:01
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost wpa_action: WPA_IFACE=wlan0 WPA_ACTION=DISCONNECTED
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost wpa_action: WPA_ID=0 WPA_ID_STR=home WPA_CTRL_DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost wpa_action: ifdown wlan0
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.117 on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3701f86b)
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.1.117 from 192.168.1.1
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost dhclient: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.117 from 192.168.1.1
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost dhclient: All rights reserved.
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost dhclient: 
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.117.
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.117 on wlan0.IPv4.
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost dhclient: Listening on LPF/wlan0/7c:ec:79:cb:3f:01
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost dhclient: Sending on   LPF/wlan0/7c:ec:79:cb:3f:01
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Dec 18 22:33:37 localhost dhclient: DHCPRELEASE on wlan0 to 192.168.1.1 port 67 (xid=0x102f0b30)
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.117 on wlan0.
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.117.
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost kernel: [   40.889995] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost kernel: [   40.929706] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 3
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost kernel: [   40.929723] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 2
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost kernel: [   40.929733] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 1
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost kernel: [   40.929741] wlan0: Removed STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost kernel: [   40.930384] wlan0: Destroyed STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost wpa_supplicant[815]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:25:9c:4d:18:36 reason=3
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::7eec:79ff:fecb:3f01.
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost kernel: [   40.952029] wlcore: down
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::7eec:79ff:fecb:3f01 on wlan0.
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost kernel: [   40.960826] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost kernel: [   40.960844] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost kernel: [   40.960856] cfg80211: Kicking the queue
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost kernel: [   40.960877] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost kernel: [   41.016867] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz with regulatory rule:
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost kernel: [   41.016883] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost wpa_action: removing sendsigs omission pidfile: /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid
Dec 18 22:33:38 localhost dbus[512]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.UPower' (using servicehelper)
Dec 18 22:33:39 localhost kernel: [   41.917136] wlcore: PHY firmware version: Rev 8.2.0.0.232
Dec 18 22:33:39 localhost kernel: [   42.050647] wlcore: firmware booted (Rev 8.9.0.0.48)
Dec 18 22:33:39 localhost kernel: [   42.121592] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Dec 18 22:33:39 localhost dbus[512]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.UPower'
Dec 18 22:33:39 localhost wpa_action: WPA_IFACE=wlan0 WPA_ACTION=CONNECTED
Dec 18 22:33:39 localhost wpa_action: WPA_ID=0 WPA_ID_STR=home WPA_CTRL_DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
Dec 18 22:33:39 localhost wpa_action: ifup wlan0=home
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost dbus[512]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.UDisks2' (using servicehelper)
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost wpa_supplicant[815]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 (SSID='MYWIFI' freq=2462 MHz)
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost kernel: [   42.785934] wlan0: authenticate with 00:25:9c:4d:18:36
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost kernel: [   42.785957] wlan0: Allocated STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost kernel: [   42.794503] wlan0: Inserted STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost kernel: [   42.794523] wlan0: send auth to 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 (try 1/3)
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost wpa_supplicant[815]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 (SSID='MYWIFI' freq=2462 MHz)
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost kernel: [   42.807552] wlan0: authenticated
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost kernel: [   42.807572] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 2
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost kernel: [   42.809465] wlan0: associate with 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 (try 1/3)
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost kernel: [   42.813732] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost kernel: [   42.813758] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 3
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost kernel: [   42.837965] wlan0: associated
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost kernel: [   42.838003] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost wpa_supplicant[815]: wlan0: Associated with 00:25:9c:4d:18:36
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost kernel: [   42.849274] wlan0: dropped frame to 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 (unauthorized port)
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost dhclient: All rights reserved.
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost dhclient: 
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost wpa_supplicant[815]: wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost wpa_supplicant[815]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 completed (reauth) [id=0 id_str=home]
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost kernel: [   42.882667] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 4
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost kernel: [   42.887484] wlcore: Association completed.
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost udisksd[2320]: udisks daemon version 2.1.3 starting
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost dhclient: Listening on LPF/wlan0/7c:ec:79:cb:3f:01
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost dhclient: Sending on   LPF/wlan0/7c:ec:79:cb:3f:01
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xab408b06)
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost ntpdate[2067]: Can't find host 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost ntpdate[2067]: Can't find host 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost ntpdate[2067]: Can't find host 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost ntpdate[2067]: Can't find host ntp.ubuntu.com: Name or service not known (-2)
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost ntpdate[2067]: sendto(193.104.37.238): Success
Dec 18 22:33:40 localhost dbus[512]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2'
Dec 18 22:33:41 localhost udisksd[2320]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the system message bus
Dec 18 22:33:41 localhost ntpdate[2067]: sendto(193.190.253.212): Success
Dec 18 22:33:41 localhost ntpdate[2067]: sendto(85.88.55.5): Success
Dec 18 22:33:41 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::7eec:79ff:fecb:3f01.
Dec 18 22:33:41 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Dec 18 22:33:41 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Registering new address record for fe80::7eec:79ff:fecb:3f01 on wlan0.*.
Dec 18 22:33:42 localhost NetworkManager[1024]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
Dec 18 22:33:42 localhost ntpdate[2067]: sendto(193.104.37.238): Success
Dec 18 22:33:43 localhost ntpdate[2067]: sendto(193.190.253.212): Success
Dec 18 22:33:43 localhost ntpdate[2067]: sendto(85.88.55.5): Success
Dec 18 22:33:43 localhost dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0xab408b06)
Dec 18 22:33:44 localhost dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.117 on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x68b40ab)
Dec 18 22:33:44 localhost dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.1.117 from 192.168.1.1
Dec 18 22:33:44 localhost dhclient: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.117 from 192.168.1.1
Dec 18 22:33:44 localhost ntpdate[2067]: sendto(193.104.37.238): Success
Dec 18 22:33:44 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.117.
Dec 18 22:33:44 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Dec 18 22:33:44 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.117 on wlan0.IPv4.
Dec 18 22:33:45 localhost dhclient: bound to 192.168.1.117 -- renewal in 42573 seconds.
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost wpa_action: creating sendsigs omission pidfile: /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost wpa_action: bssid=00:25:9c:4d:18:36
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost wpa_action: ssid=MYWIFI
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost wpa_action: id=0
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost wpa_action: id_str=home
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost wpa_action: mode=station
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost wpa_action: pairwise_cipher=CCMP
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost wpa_action: group_cipher=CCMP
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost wpa_action: key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost wpa_action: wpa_state=COMPLETED
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost wpa_action: ip_address=192.168.1.117
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost wpa_action: p2p_device_address=7c:ec:79:cb:3f:01
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost wpa_action: address=7c:ec:79:cb:3f:01
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost wpa_action: WPA_IFACE=wlan0 WPA_ACTION=DISCONNECTED
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost wpa_action: WPA_ID=0 WPA_ID_STR=home WPA_CTRL_DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost wpa_action: ifdown wlan0
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost ntpdate[2067]: adjust time server 193.190.253.212 offset 0.001129 sec
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost dhclient: 
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost dhclient: Listening on LPF/wlan0/7c:ec:79:cb:3f:01
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost dhclient: Sending on   LPF/wlan0/7c:ec:79:cb:3f:01
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost dhclient: DHCPRELEASE on wlan0 to 192.168.1.1 port 67 (xid=0x6b12994)
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost ntpd[2559]: ntpd 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Wed Nov 11 18:05:09 UTC 2015 (1)
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost ntpd[2560]: proto: precision = 0.666 usec
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost ntpd[2560]: ntp_io: estimated max descriptors: 1024, initial socket boundary: 16
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost ntpd[2560]: Listen and drop on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0 UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost ntpd[2560]: Listen and drop on 1 v6wildcard :: UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost ntpd[2560]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1 UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost ntpd[2560]: Listen normally on 3 wlan0 192.168.1.117 UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost ntpd[2560]: Listen normally on 4 usb0 192.168.7.2 UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost ntpd[2560]: Listen normally on 5 lo ::1 UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost ntpd[2560]: Listen normally on 6 usb0 fe80::4c71:9eff:fe8c:405b UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost ntpd[2560]: Listen normally on 7 wlan0 fe80::7eec:79ff:fecb:3f01 UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost ntpd[2560]: peers refreshed
Dec 18 22:33:47 localhost ntpd[2560]: Listening on routing socket on fd #24 for interface updates
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.117 on wlan0.
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.117.
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost kernel: [   50.954532] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost wpa_supplicant[815]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:25:9c:4d:18:36 reason=3
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost kernel: [   50.989766] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 3
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost kernel: [   50.989786] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 2
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost kernel: [   50.989796] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 1
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost kernel: [   50.989806] wlan0: Removed STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost kernel: [   50.990182] wlan0: Destroyed STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost kernel: [   50.996900] wlcore: down
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::7eec:79ff:fecb:3f01.
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::7eec:79ff:fecb:3f01 on wlan0.
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost kernel: [   51.003580] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost kernel: [   51.003598] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost kernel: [   51.003609] cfg80211: Kicking the queue
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost kernel: [   51.003629] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost kernel: [   51.033463] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz with regulatory rule:
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost wpa_action: removing sendsigs omission pidfile: /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost kernel: [   51.689265] wlcore: PHY firmware version: Rev 8.2.0.0.232
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost kernel: [   51.732232] wlcore: firmware booted (Rev 8.9.0.0.48)
Dec 18 22:33:48 localhost kernel: [   51.751504] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost wpa_action: WPA_IFACE=wlan0 WPA_ACTION=CONNECTED
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost wpa_action: WPA_ID=0 WPA_ID_STR=home WPA_CTRL_DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost wpa_action: ifup wlan0=home
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost dhclient: All rights reserved.
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost dhclient: 
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost dhclient: Listening on LPF/wlan0/7c:ec:79:cb:3f:01
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost dhclient: Sending on   LPF/wlan0/7c:ec:79:cb:3f:01
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x59b31d7e)
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost wpa_supplicant[815]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 (SSID='MYWIFI' freq=2462 MHz)
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost kernel: [   52.422467] wlan0: authenticate with 00:25:9c:4d:18:36
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost kernel: [   52.422491] wlan0: Allocated STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost kernel: [   52.425806] wlan0: Inserted STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost kernel: [   52.425824] wlan0: send auth to 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 (try 1/3)
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost wpa_supplicant[815]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 (SSID='MYWIFI' freq=2462 MHz)
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost kernel: [   52.443755] wlan0: authenticated
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost kernel: [   52.443778] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 2
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost kernel: [   52.448691] wlan0: associate with 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 (try 1/3)
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost kernel: [   52.452972] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost kernel: [   52.453001] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 3
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost wpa_supplicant[815]: wlan0: Associated with 00:25:9c:4d:18:36
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost kernel: [   52.460902] wlan0: associated
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost kernel: [   52.460938] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost kernel: [   52.478579] wlan0: dropped frame to 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 (unauthorized port)
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost wpa_supplicant[815]: wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost wpa_supplicant[815]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 completed (reauth) [id=0 id_str=home]
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost kernel: [   52.492755] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 4
Dec 18 22:33:49 localhost kernel: [   52.493101] wlcore: Association completed.
Dec 18 22:33:50 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::7eec:79ff:fecb:3f01.
Dec 18 22:33:50 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Dec 18 22:33:50 localhost avahi-daemon[577]: Registering new address record for fe80::7eec:79ff:fecb:3f01 on wlan0.*.
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpd[2560]: ntpd exiting on signal 15
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpdate[2689]: Can't find host 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpdate[2689]: Can't find host 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpdate[2689]: Can't find host 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpdate[2689]: Can't find host 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpdate[2689]: Can't find host ntp.ubuntu.com: Name or service not known (-2)
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpdate[2689]: no servers can be used, exiting
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpd[2720]: ntpd 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Wed Nov 11 18:05:09 UTC 2015 (1)
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpd[2721]: proto: precision = 0.667 usec
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpd[2721]: ntp_io: estimated max descriptors: 1024, initial socket boundary: 16
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpd[2721]: Listen and drop on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0 UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpd[2721]: Listen and drop on 1 v6wildcard :: UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpd[2721]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1 UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpd[2721]: Listen normally on 3 usb0 192.168.7.2 UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpd[2721]: Listen normally on 4 lo ::1 UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpd[2721]: Listen normally on 5 usb0 fe80::4c71:9eff:fe8c:405b UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpd[2721]: Listen normally on 6 wlan0 fe80::7eec:79ff:fecb:3f01 UDP 123
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpd[2721]: peers refreshed
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpd[2721]: Listening on routing socket on fd #23 for interface updates
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpd[2721]: Deferring DNS for 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org 1
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpd[2721]: Deferring DNS for 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org 1
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpd[2721]: Deferring DNS for 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org 1
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpd[2721]: Deferring DNS for 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org 1
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpd[2721]: Deferring DNS for ntp.ubuntu.com 1
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpd[2725]: signal_no_reset: signal 17 had flags 4000000
Dec 18 22:33:51 localhost ntpd[2721]: ntpd exiting on signal 15
```

dmeg output (filtering wlan0)

```
[  737.984415] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  738.003029] wlan0: dropped frame to 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 (unauthorized port)
[  738.027517] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 4
[  742.690201] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  742.714889] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 3
[  742.714906] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 2
[  742.714916] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 1
[  742.714925] wlan0: Removed STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36
[  742.715405] wlan0: Destroyed STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36
[  743.359582] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  744.014634] wlan0: authenticate with 00:25:9c:4d:18:36
[  744.014676] wlan0: Allocated STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36
[  744.020416] wlan0: Inserted STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36
[  744.020453] wlan0: send auth to 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 (try 1/3)
[  744.042476] wlan0: authenticated
[  744.042515] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 2
[  744.045329] wlan0: associate with 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 (try 1/3)
[  744.049740] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[  744.049787] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 3
[  744.067155] wlan0: associated
[  744.067218] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  744.085215] wlan0: dropped frame to 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 (unauthorized port)
[  744.106893] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 4
[  749.441918] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  749.478623] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 3
[  749.478660] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 2
[  749.478684] wlan0: moving STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 to state 1
[  749.478704] wlan0: Removed STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36
[  749.480041] wlan0: Destroyed STA 00:25:9c:4d:18:36
```

I'm not having this issue if I replace

```
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

with

```
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

With the `wpa-conf` configuration, My OpenVPN client starts fine, and the WIFI connection is also stable. The problem however with `wpa-conf` is that when the WIFI connection drops (and this typically happens after about 12 hours), it doesn't automatically reconnect anymore.

What is the best way to setup an OpenVPN client over wlan0, while keeping the WIFI connection stable, and allowing it to reconnect when the WIFI connection drops.

Comment: What does the syslog say? Or `dmesg`?

Comment: added syslog and dmesg output. It's just constantly connecting / disconnecting again. as soon I shut down the openvpn service it stops. Read somewhere that when the openvpn tun0 interface comes up the roaming device get shut down. But I don't if this is the root cause and if so, how can I avoid it.

Comment: `wlan0: dropped frame to 00:25:9c:4d:18:36 (unauthorized port)` - that's interesting. What kernel version are you using? Are you able to try a newer kernel?

Comment: Not really ... it's a UDOO Neo board running the latest supported kernel.